# A way to request copy editing on my posts

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

My English is poor, but my answers are not so poor ("see votes count"). I would like to improve the grammar and writing of my answers, but, right now, I do not have sufficient skills.

I even have placed this phrase — "feel free to edit my poor English posts" — in the "About me" section, but without any result.

Does it make sense to propose a functionality which addresses these needs? Something like "Please edit me" button. Such functionality will help:

- non-native speakers with sufficiently high reputation — to improve their English;
- low reputation native speakers — to gain some initial reputation.

If no, is it possible to use Meta for such an individual request, or to create a <s>community wiki</s> common question for such requests? Possible structure of a request is as follows.

> **From user 7879193**
>
> - questions: [user:7879193 created:2017-05-01..2018-02-01](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a7879193%20created%3a2017-05-01..2018-02-01)
>     (10—100 posts);
> - user local time: UTC+5
>     (to approve suggested edits by post owner and not through review queue)
> - editor: user xxxxxxxxx;
> - status: in progress

Comment: I'm glad you want your answers to be better (from a grammatical sense), but I don't think we need a specific feature for this. I see posts being edited into clearer English all the time, without a prompt.

Comment: So you want to draw attention to editors, to edit specific posts? A chatroom might be a better tool than a CW or MSO question.

Comment: Imperfect English from a non-native speaker, (aided and abetted by Google Translate), is not usually a problem.  Certainly not such a problem as the more usual no code, no inputs, no outputs, no functional description, no error-messages, poor formatting/indentation, no test details, no test data, no debugging details etc etc that plague so many questions posed in clear English:(

Comment: I think having a queue where people can put posts they think should be edited can improve the quality of content on SO.

Comment: That, or delete any chance we have of new users doing it themselves instead of just leaving others to do it @Oleg.

Comment: Thank you, guys. George, as it seems, reviewers do not like "pure grammatical" suggested edits. Martin James, this "language service" is rather for answers than for questions (BTW, this is my first question on SE sites, please feel free to edit grammar etc :))

Comment: The problem with such services is that a 3rd person is introduced between the OP and answeriing user.   This can go slightly wrong, eg. a misunderstanding on either path that is easily cleard up, (but with yet more effort), or can result in a fight over meaning, terminology, syntax, grammar etc with some poor user who tried to help both sides stuck in the middle.  I mean, arguing/arbitrating between one or both sides of a meeting is fine if you're being paid $$$/hr.  Volunteeers should not be exposed to it:(

Comment: @StanislavKralin 'feel free to edit grammar' nah - your written English is excellent:)

Comment: ..in fact, to try and get some sympathy votes, you may wish to consider making more language errors in future, (just not in source code:).

Comment: Thanks again. It seems that the correct answer is something like "one better should register on https://ell.stackexchange.com/ ".

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I was talking rather about wide ranges of questions, than about individual ones...

Comment: *George, as it seems, reviewers do not like "pure grammatical" suggested edits.* What makes you think so? Honestly, I'd rather see more edits that only fix the grammar than tag-only edits, edits that only make the code less indented, and edits that add unnecessary formatting.

Comment: I sometimes ask in a chatroom a frequent to proofread posts from me. I posted on ELL.se once but that didn't go well, IMO. Never re-tried that route,

Comment: [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212385/translation-help-review-queue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like the motivation but I don't feel like such a system is long-term sustainable.

The only way that community edits happen nowadays is when someone stumbles on a question or answer, believes it to be high quality, and wishes to convey that to the rest of the world.  This happens in a very ad-hoc and asynchronous fashion.

If your posts aren't getting edited, it could mean one of two things:

- Your posts were clear enough to enough people such that they didn't see the need to improve the structure of it.
- There aren't enough eyes on the subject matter itself and it has a knock-on effect; not enough eyes means not enough people thinking it can be improved.

Asking users to always improve your grammar is also a fairly large ask.  When I do improvements I usually look to do them in a narrow yet impactful way; like you, I volunteer my time and energy and wish to do so in the most useful way possible.  I don't feel like always editing a specific user's posts is the most impactful.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, the reason seems to be that my favorite tags are little quiet backwater. This has both advantages and disadvantages.